# Correct way of filtering an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I was wondering what the correct or best performing way of filtering an `ObservableCollection` is. I wrote some pseudo code down below that represents the way that I've been doing it until now. Is this performance efficient and how can this be improved ?
From what I know, `ObservableCollection` collections are usually not supposed to be recreated but just have their contents modified. As you can see my approach does not follow that principle.

This is my approach:

```cs
// The objects collection is filled from a database at start
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> objects = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
// This property is bound to the view
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> DataToDisplay
{
    get => FilterData(/* list of parameter values */);
    private set => objects = value;
}
```

And this is the logic I use when filtering the collection with different parameters:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> FilterData(/* list of parameter values */)
{
    if (/* if no parameters search values are input return full collection */)
        return objects;

    IEnumerable<MyClass> temp = objects;
    try
    {
        if (/* if param 1 is input */)
            temp = temp.Where((x) => x.Param1 == Param1SearchValue);
        if (/* if param 2 is input */)
            temp = temp.Where((x) => x.Param2 == Param1SearchValue);
        .
        .
        .
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        /* Write to log if an error is encountered */
    }

    return new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(temp);
}
```

**Edit:**
I want to rephrase my question a bit. Can someone provide a piece of code that is more efficient than the code I gave above? Is there something I can change to make this code faster or should I look for a better way to store my data?

**For the Context of use:**
The collection of data is bound to a view that needs to be updated when the use enters a search criteria. The user has many different parameters he can use to search the collection like Name, Store, Income etc.

Comment: "usually not supposed". Maybe but the question is rather what do you need in your concrete code.  We don't know if you for what you do need a copy or not. If you filter "inplace" on objects you can't unfilter for example. Or you can't have multiple filterings concurrently. You might want to look if you rather want a [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) here.

Comment: It seems that the `CollectionView` is a rather obsolete pattern. I am trying to figure out the best way to actually filter and sort an `ObservableCollection`. The code I provided served me well, but I would like to know If there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: When you filter the collection, do you need to update the original collection or just return an enumeration of the filtered data?

If you just need an enumeration, the type that FilterData returns doesn't even have to be an ObservableCollection, you can just return the IEnumerable created by Linq.Where().

If you do need to update the source collection, keep in mind that assigning it to ´new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(temp);´ will not keep the eventhandler that the old collection had. (So don't do it!)

Comment: I keep using `ObservableCollection` for the sake of simplicity as it notifies the view automatically without me having to do so in code. I am not looking for a single way of doing it like filtering the collection in place. I want to know what the best way to search a collection is, doesn't matter if I need to copy it to another or do it in place. I am working on large datasets and performance becomes crucial really quick.